# Set root path for relative links while converting with Pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I have a markdown file which I want to convert into html file using `pandoc`.

It has some relative links in the form `[text](relative_path.MD)`

After conversion I want this links to lead to `https://github.com/username/project/blob/master/relative_path.MD`

In other words I want to set `https://github.com/username/project/blob/master/` as a root for relative paths. Can I do this in some simple way?

I found that I can [write arbitrary Lua filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569597/pandoc-filters-change-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths), but surely I am not the first person trying to achieve this and there is some built-in method allowing to do this without writing own link parsing code?

Comment: Would it help to use a [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element in your html code?

Comment: @AxelKemper Not really, as I am trying to generate HTML and use it as a part of page. But in general it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this filter:

https://musteresel.github.io/posts/2018/01/pandoc-project-relative-links.html

It's in Haskell rather than Lua so won't be as efficient as a lua filter.

No idea if it works!

Comment: I'm the author of that filter. It works by replacing links such as `/my/thing.html` with `path/to/somewhere/my/thing.html` if you give it `path/to/somewhere` as "argument" (via metadata). It's a compiled Haskell program, so unless you plan to use it on hundreds of thousands of pages efficience won't be an issue. I also have a Python variant of that filter in personal use here: https://github.com/musteresel/musteresel.github.io/blob/sources-master/utils/project-rel-links/prl.py